# What's the easiest or idiomatic way to mock HTTP requests in 3rd party js libraries with node / js

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, http, testing

When I've coded in Ruby or Python, I've been able to use libraries like [VCR](https://github.com/vcr/vcr) that intercept HTTP requests, and record them, so when for example I'm hitting an 3rd party API in tests, I can save that response as a fixture instead of manually building a huge mock objects to check behaviour against.

It's not perfect, but it has saved a load of time when I've been exploring which API requests to make against a third party API, (often wrapping a 3rd party library), then writing tests to check this behaviour.

#### What's the closest thing in JS these days to this?

I'm looking for an open source tool I can `require` in my test files, so when I run tests where I might call methods on third party APIs, I don't make expensive, slow HTTP requests. I imagine the code might look a bit like:

```
it('does something I expect it to', () {

  // set up some state I care about
  let someVar = someSetupCode()

  let library = thirdPartyLib({creds: 'somecreds'})
  library.someMethod()

  // check state has changed 
  expect(someVar.value).toBe('what I Expect after calling someMethod')

})
```

Where here, when I call `library.someMethod()`, instead of hitting actual servers, I'm checking against the values the server would be returning, that I've saved previously.

**Monkey patching an existing library or function**

I see things [fetch-vcr](https://www.npmjs.com/package/fetch-vcr), or [axios-vcr](https://www.npmjs.com/package/axios-vcr), but these seem to rely on explicitly reaching into a library to replace say, a call to `fetch` with the http-intercepting version instead, be reading a 'cassette' file containing the canned response.

I'm looking for a way to avoid patching 3rd party code if I can help it, a this is how I understand VCR works for other languages.

Presumably, if there's an HTTP client built somewhere into node then that would be the place you'd patch a function - I haven't come across a specific library that does this.

**Running an entire HTTP server**

Alternatively I can see libraries like [vcr.js](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vcr.js), or [yakbak](http://code.flickr.net/2016/04/25/introducing-yakbak-record-and-playback-http-interactions-in-nodejs/), which essentially set up an HTTP server which serves JSON blobs you define, at various urls, like serving a saved `users.json` file at `http://localhost:8100/users/`

This is okay, but again, if I don't need to spin up a whole HTTP server, and make actual HTTP requests, that would be wonderful.

Comment: What about [json-server](https://medium.com/codingthesmartway-com-blog/create-a-rest-api-with-json-server-36da8680136d) ?

Answer (score 0):

Oh, hang on, it looks like [sepia](https://github.com/linkedin/sepia) from linkedin works well for nodejs at least.

I haven't looked into it too much, but I'd welcome comments if you have been using it.

Answer (score 0):

Probably [SoapUI](https://www.soapui.org/) works for you. Although its name, it also works with REST API.